# Batch transform single cells into merged cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have many single cells, and would like to make them into merged cells. i.e. each cell is converted to a merged cell from two single cells. How to quickly achieve this for dozens of cells?

[image]

Comment: You will need to write a VBA macro. Start by recording a macro; then edit it to apply to your actual use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume your data is in row 1 and the merged data will be in row 4 like in your example.

1. Create one merged cell pair in A4:B4
2. Enter this formula in A4 `=INDEX(1:1,INT((COLUMN()-1)/2)+1)`
3. Grab the fill handle on the merged pair A4:B4 and drag it horizontally until its got twice the number of columns than in row 1.

If required, you can then copy the whole row 4 and paste it in the 3rd row down from any other row of data you wish to separate into merged cells.

Comment: LibrOffice 6.4.7.2: Step 3. copy and then paste, a single right cursor after each paste.